# What's the correct pattern in ember for a computed property that's dependent on both model & controller properties?

Tags: ember.js

We have a series of chained computed properties in our model, like so:

```
App.MyModel = Em.Object.extend({
  value0: 2
  value1: 5,
  value2: function() {
    return this.get('value1') + this.get('value0');
  }.property('value1', 'value0'),
  value3: function() {
    return this.get('value2') * this.get('value0');
  }.property('value2', 'value0')
});
```

We now want the `value0` attribute to be bound to a value in an ArrayController.  What is the most correct way to accomplish this?

This is the approach we've used for now:

```
App.MyController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  value0: function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      this.setEach('value0', value);
    }
    return this.get('firstObject.value0');
  }.property('firstObject.value0')
});
```

It feels messy to need to set the attribute on every object.  Is there a better way?

EDIT:

Another approach we've been batting around is defining a `call` handlebars helper, which would allow something like this:

```
{{#each controller}}
   <li>{{call someModelMethod someControllerProperty}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

And then the model looks like this:

```
App.MyModel = Em.Object.extend({
  value1: 5,
  someModelMethod: function(value0) {
    return this.get('value1') * value0;
  }
});
```

This feels better to me, thoughts?

Comment: Your example is a bit too abstract for me to understand what you're trying to accomplish here.